# Show $x^2+y^2=9z+3$ has no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show $x^2+y^2=9z+3$ has no integer solutions

So I know that $x^2+y^2=3(3z+1)$

And since $3\mid (9z+3)$ and $3\not\mid (3z+1)$ then $9z+3$ cannot be a square since it has a prime divisor which has a power less then $2$.

So does know this isn't a pythagorean triple $(x,y,\sqrt{9z+3})$ give me that there are no solutions or do I have to show more?

Comment: If was nowhere said that $9z+3$ must be a square.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not enough: $x^2+y^2=18$ has solutions even though $18$ is not a square.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be a pythogorean triplet?  Lots of numbers aren't so that surely doesn't imply no solutions.  $8^2 + 5^2=89$ is not a pythogorean triplet but.... there you are.

Comment: to show no solutions, look modulo $9$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Or modulo $3$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier:  I meant $x^2+y^2\not\equiv9z+3\equiv3\pmod9$; you can't say prima facie $x^2+y^2\not\equiv9z+3=0\pmod3$ because $x\equiv y\equiv0\pmod3$ provides a solution

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not saying you're wrong, as automaticallyGenerated 's answer explained nicely btw, just saying it's not the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2 + y^2 = 9z+3$ must be true, it must also be true that $$x^2+y^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$$

However, if we list out $x^2 \pmod 9$ for $0 \le x < 9$, we get $$0, 1, 4, 0, 7, 7, 0, 4, 1$$

There is no way of adding two numbers from $0, 1, 4, 7$ such that the sum is equal to $0 \pmod 9$.

Therefore, $x^2 + y^2 = 9z + 3$ has no integer solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** if $n$ is an integer then $n^2\bmod 3$ is $0$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$, and is $1$ otherwise.

In what case can it happen that $x^2+y^2$ is a multiple of $3$ then?

Answer (score 2):

You've shown that $3|9x + 3$.  You've also shown that $9\not \mid 9x+3$.

SO that means $3|x^2 + y^2$ so but $9\not \mid x^2 + y^2$.

If $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $3$ then $x^2 + y^2$ is divisible by $9$.  So that's out.  If one of $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $3$ but the other isn't then $x^2 + y^2$ is not divisible by $3$ and that's out.

So the only options is neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $3$.

So $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$ and $y \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$.  Which means $x^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $y^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

So $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $3\not \mid x^2 + y^2$ so that's out.

So all three options are out.